# Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation for allocation of an array of struct

Tags: c, valgrind

Valgrind is complaining about a method and I really cannot figure out why. The error message I get is following:

```
==1664==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==1664==    at 0x47F1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==1664==    by 0x100004B6A: filter_my_struct_list (main.c:3357)
==1664==    by 0x100002C7C: main (main.c:370)
```

In the method he complains about I am just trying to "compress" a list, meaning, I am merging consecutive elements of my structure to one.

my_struct is just a structure with two int values:

```
typedef struct {
   int start;
   int len;
} my_struct;
```

And the method looks like:

```
 my_struct* filter_my_struct_list(my_struct *listl, int *elements_in_list) {

my_struct *compressed_list;
if (*elements_in_list == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Number of my_structs should not be zero! Please check the      input!\n");
    exit(1);
} else if (*elements_in_list == 1) {
    compressed_list = malloc(sizeof(my_struct)* 1);
    my_struct f = {listl[0].start, listl[0].len};
    compressed_list[0] = f;
    return compressed_list;
}

int fst, remained_index;
remained_index = fst = 0;

compressed_list = malloc(sizeof(my_struct) * (*elements_in_list)); //<== The line valgrind doesn't like

while (fst < (*elements_in_list - 1)) {

    int fst_in_loop = fst;
    int nxt = fst_in_loop + 1;
    BOOL terminate = FALSE;

    while (!terminate) {

        if (((listl[fst_in_loop].start + listl[fst_in_loop].len) == listl[nxt].start)) {
            fst_in_loop++;
            nxt++;
        } else terminate = TRUE;

        if (nxt == (*elements_in_list)) {
            terminate = TRUE;
        }
    }

    if (fst_in_loop != fst) {

        int new_len = listl[fst_in_loop].start
                + listl[fst_in_loop].len - listl[fst].start;

        my_struct f = {listl[fst].start, new_len};
        compressed_list[remained_index] = f;

    } else {
        my_struct f = {listl[fst].start, listl[fst].len};
        compressed_list[remained_index] = f;
    }

    remained_index++;
    fst = nxt;
    if (nxt == (*elements_in_list - 1)) {

        if (fst == fst_in_loop) {

            int f_1;
            for (f_1 = fst; f_1 <= nxt; f_1++) {
                my_struct f = {listl[f_1].start, listl[f_1].len};
                compressed_list[remained_index] = f;
                remained_index++;
            }

        } else {
            my_struct f = {listl[nxt].start, listl[nxt].len};
            compressed_list[remained_index] = f;
            remained_index++;
        }
    }
}
*elements_in_list = remained_index;
return compressed_list;
```

}

Why is he telling me it is not initialised since I am catching the cases when there are less than two elements to be merged??

EDIT:

Ok i just found out, when I call only this method, the error disappears, but as soon as I reuse my list, the error appears

Comment: please indicate the line number in your code - i.e. lines numbered 3172 and 3358 as indicated by valgrind

Comment: sorry, I removed the alloc, is an unimportant malloc macro, and I indicated the line where the problem is; But see my second post, there is my actual problem

Comment: `int fst_in_loop = fst;
    int nxt = fst_in_loop + 1;
    BOOL terminate = FALSE;` is a terribly complicated way to compare two adjacent elements, IMHO.(you use three variables while you only need one)

Comment: agree with joop: I don't see what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Why does it matter? IF I do it on the complicated or not-complicated way.. 
I didn't get a better way when I did it, like I said: I check how many elements in the list are consecutive( meaning start+length is equal start of the next element), and then I save the index of the last consecutive element, and generate one element instead of all of the consecutives

Comment: it matters: you want us to debug your code, but I for one don't understand what you're trying to do. break it down to a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this may also enable you to debug it yourself.

Comment: `Why does it matter?` Your code tries to maintain three varables where only one is needed. (a human reader can only keep track of < ~7 simultanious entities) A simple loop like this can be human-read in one pass; but only if it is kept simple. (your debugger may understand it, but you still won't understand your debugger)

Comment: The problem is probably that you use the `*elements_in_list` function argument both as an `in` parameter (the size of the original list) and as an `out` parameter (the size of the freshly allocated resulting "compressed" list)

Comment: Hmm ok, could make sense. But How can I do it differently? I can only return one variable, so that is why i thought using a pointer for the size of the new list makes sense